# Using phone's computing power to assist in PC's calculation

Tags: cpu

Is phone cluster or cluster with PC and phones possible?

I was thinking if recoding MOSIX or using any other program/software to connect your phone with PC and let the PC use phone's computing power in calculations is possible.

I know that it won't boost it a lot, but mostly just for an experiment.

Comment: Welcome to [android.se]. I edited the title to represent the actual issue. If I accidentally changed the intent of this post, feel free to [edit] and rollback/improve it.

Answer (score 0):

A modern smartphone that runs Android is a general-purpose computer. Yes, you can run a single or cluster of smartphones to do general-purpose computation.

A smartphone is probably not the best tool for this job. Phones are expensive because they are optimized for size and power considerations. A desktop or laptop computer will be give you significantly more computing performance for the same cost.

Comment: i know it's not best ratio price to efficency but i was thinking more when you enter let say some Institute you connect to their network and can share you computing power. So i wasn't sure if it's possible.