# Can multiple androids be paired to work on the same task?

Tags: superuser, task-management, multiple-devices

PlayStation 3 consoles were combined to make a super computer. Can the Android phones be modified in the same way? Could I use the processing power of 2 phones to play a movie that 1 would not.

https://www.engadget.com/2007/08/11/sonys-warhawk-server-farm-is-made-of-ps3s/

[image]

Comment: Yes, see https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/168142/using-phones-computing-power-to-assist-in-pcs-calculation/168146#168146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the workload but you absolutely could use Android phones as a cluster in much the same way they did with the PS3's.

You'd probably need some sort of server-client setup. With a server setup to manage the clients, assign work and manage the overall process and the clients setup to complete the work.

This is an interesting idea, for sure!